# Derivative Fisher's Criterion

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am currently reading "Pattern recognition and machine learning" by Bishop. In section 4.1.4 the Fisher's Criterion is stated as: 
$$J(w)=\frac{w^TS_Bw}{w^TS_Ww}$$
where $w$ is a column vector, and $S_B$ and $S_W$ are symmetric matrices. I now want to calculate the derivative of that function, but only came this far using the quotient rule: 
\begin{align}
\frac{dJ(w)}{dw} 
&=\frac{(w^TS_Bw)'w^TS_Ww-w^TS_Bw(w^TS_Ww)'}{(w^TS_Ww)^2}
\end{align}

How do I calculate $(w^TS_Bw)'$ and $(w^TS_Ww)'$ ?

I do get it's ought to be
$S_B w$ and $S_W w$, but I do not get why, especially because it is stated here: 
http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf
that $\frac{\partial x^T A x}{\partial x} = x^T (A + A^T)$ when $x$ is a column vector and $A$ is a matrix.

Comment: Play with the idea that you take transposes. The result is a scalar so it is it's own transpose, right? Now what happens to the expression if we do that.

Comment: There are 2 conventions for expressing vector derivatives, which are transposes of each other.  You are comparing source material from two authors who have chosen opposite conventions. You must mentally translate between them.

Answer (score 1):

In Bishop the convention is that the derivative of a scalar function with respect to a vector variable is a column vector. This can be seen in one of the formulas in his Matrix Derivatives section:
$$
{\partial\over \partial {\bf x}}({\bf x}^T{\bf a})
={\partial\over \partial {\bf x}}({\bf a}^T{\bf x})
={\bf a}\tag{C.19}
$$
By this convention, you can prove that if $\bf A$ is a (conformable) constant matrix, then
$$
{\partial\over \partial {\bf x}}({\bf x}^T{\bf Ax})=({\bf A} + {\bf A}^T){\bf x}
$$
To get your result you use the fact that both $S_B$ and $S_W$ are symmetric matrices, so they are equal to their transposes.

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't that lead to $(w^TS_Bw)' = (S_B + S_B^T) w = 2 S_B w$?

Comment: @Sleik Yes. The factor of 2 doesn't matter